# VSCode and VS2017 works differently when the Column Selection Row count of copy and paste are different

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

I am writing copy paste in VS2017, as shown in the below gif (vs2017.gif):

[image: vs2017.gif]

However, VSCode works differently when the row count of multi-cursor is different.

[image: vscode.gif]

Is there a copy paste method to insert blank information when the row count is different, as in VS2017?

---

**2021-09-10 17:40 UPDATE**

If the Copy Row Count and the Paste Row are the same,
it works, as shown in here in vscode_Ok.gif:

[image: vscode_Ok.gif]

But if the Copy Row Count and the Paste Row are different, it doesn't work, as shown here in vscode_Fail.gif:

[image: vscode_Fail.gif]

I don't want to put the copied multiple rows in each row.
Instead, I'm looking for a way to make VSCode behave like vs2017.gif, the very first gif shown above.

Comment: `Column Selection` is not `Multi Cursor` it is a separate mode of `Select`, In `Multi Cursor` if you reduce down to 1 cursor you get all the selected regions

Comment: The only way I found to go around that is after copy pasting the way you did, I inserted a cursor after a and b and ***then*** I copy pasted, so I guess that's what you mean when you say same cursor row count?

Comment: I will change the title Column Selection

Comment: 2021-09-10 17:40 ADD

Comment: 2022-02-21 I'm still waiting for your answer.